# Is jgroup using checksum to become reliable on UDP?

Tags: java, messaging, checksum, multicast, jgroups

I try to understand how jgroup realized reliable multicast. I've read the manual and learned that they are using negative acks. But what happens when a cluster-member receives a corrupted message? I can't find anything about that in the official manual. (http://www.jgroups.org/manual/html_single/index.html#d0e5392)

Does somebody know if they are using checksums for the UDP-Header plus the data? Does the reveiver will request retransmission in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) already does header and data checksumming, so bad datagram will be dropped by the kernel network stack and not delivered to the userland application.

Comment: hm - I thought it's optional. Only for IPv6 it isn't. Is java UDP-Socket using checksum always?

Comment: Yes, it is optional in the RFC, but all real network stacks implement it, and on all modern network cards it's done in hardware.